# How to export a whole wordpress site including all the html css files?

Tags: wordpress, import, export

I was wondering how I can export the whole template on WordPress. There is export under tools, but it only exports the database. I have edited the WordPress template and I would want to use this template for another website. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: You don't need to export a theme - just copy the theme folder from `wp-content/themes`

Comment: oOo thanks davecoast

Answer (score 1):

I think its not enough to copy the theme folder to another WordPress because some themes needs some extra plugins to work Ex. theme builders etc.. and there may be database related configs

to clone a word press website

1. export the database using a tool like phpMyadmin
2. import database
3. copy whole WordPress website including all files (you can use [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) ftp client for this or use hosting panel. there should be a file manager compress the all files and take)
4. find the wp-config file in the root and change the new db, usernames, password ..
5. you may need to login to the wordpress dashboard -- > settings --> general and change the wordpress base URL
6. it should work

Answer (score 0):

With an FTP program you can download all the template files from /wp-content/themes/[YOUR TEMPLATE NAME]

Comment: Hello, I've been trying to do this through Filezilla. Im trying to drag and drop the file but its not letting me. I tried allowing the permission but still no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

There are different plugin for exporting Wordpress pages to HTML/CSS files.
One of them is "Export WP Page to Static HTML/CSS" from ReCorp

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft Why isn't this providing to the question? There are plugin you can use for exporting wordpress sites inclugind html/css! I just tried to help here mate..